# Is there an "in place" Toffoli gate?

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, quantum-algorithms

I am trying to implement the multiplication of a scalar in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ and a polynomial in $GF(2^n)$ in Qiskit. One naive method of implementation that I can think of is:

```
for i in qpoly.qubit_indices:
   qc.append(CCXGate(), [new_poly.qubit_indices[i], qpoly.qubit_indices[i], scalar.index])
```

Here, assume that my original quantum scalar is `scalar`, the quantum polynomial is `qpoly`, and the result is being stored in `new_poly`. `qc` is the `QuantumCircuit`, and `qubit_indices` contains the index of the qubits in the register it is called from.
I am performing a term-by-term AND of the polynomial terms with the scalar. This will work because the scalar can only be $0$ or $1$.

However, the implementation of a Toffoli gate is expensive in practice, so I would like to avoid its use as much as possible. One thing I can optimize here is to do the operation in place, that is, store the new polynomial in `qpoly` itself.

Does there exist a combination of gates that performs the AND operation in-place? If not, is there some other more efficient way to perform this multiplication? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

This isn't possible, since the associated operation wouldn't be unitary if the scalar is $0$, as it would map both $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$. The operation wouldn't be reversible and thus non-unitary.

If the scalar is classical, then it is easy to do: nothing for the $0$ case and a bunch of CNOTs for the other one.

If it's not, as you've mentioned this is a bitwise logical AND operation, for which you don't have really any other choice than to apply a bunch of Toffoli gates.

Note that not all hope for optimisation is most though: if you know that one of the control is in the $|+\rangle$ state or if you later have to uncompute this Toffoli for instance, it is possible to use lighter implementations with less CNOT and $T$ gates.

Comment: Thanks, in my case the scalar must be a qubit, it is not classical. So, I think using the Toffoli gates cannot be avoided then

Comment: @AshKetchum the fact that you always control on the same qubit may lead to some optimizations though!